# plugin cannot access to nested dependency

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I made a set of plugins.
here's my plugin's dependency:

plugin "A"

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui;visibility:=reexport,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;visibility:=reexport,
 org.eclipse.ui.console;visibility:=reexport
```

plugin "B"

```
Require-Bundle: A;visibility:=reexport
```

plugin "C"

```
Require-Bundle: B
```

plugin "C" have to accss both "A" and "B". and "B" has a 'Reexport' dependency to "A".
So, as I think, If plugin "C" has a dependency to "B", it should have dependency to "A" automatically.

But if I do so, plugin "C" cannot access to "A" neither "B". (It says "restricted access".)

a workaround is, let "C" have dependencies to "A" and "B" explicitly. like this one:

```
Require-Bundle: A,
 B
```

I'm working with eclipse 3.7 RCP developer edtion(Indigo SR2).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is OK, it's just the IDE acting a bit weird. Try to close and re-open project C; the dependencies shall resolve properly.

Although I sense a slightly bad smell here. Why not just make every plugin dependent on the core Eclipse plugins?

Comment: I tried to close and re-open, but it was no effective.
In fact, project C reconizes A, and B as its plugin dependencies, but access to them is "restricted" because of access rules.
I checked and found that A, B, C all have same access rules(accesible: \*, forbidden: \*\*/\*), and A, B are OK, but just C is not OK.